# How to disable user input (touchscreen) from command line without root

Tags: youtube, terminal, 8.0-oreo, command-line

In the android command line, I need to disable the touchscreen user inputs. I do not want to use root because I want it to be *universal* instead of device-specific (root is obviously not as widespread as non-root)
I need to do this because I want to open a youtube video using link (done already).
**And I also want to make sure that the user/person does not change / pause the video.**
I do not want to install any app whatsoever, but only use existing ones (system apps and maybe the extremely popular apps with 500m+ downloads)
I am assuming I will have all the permissions adb has (not the adb root part), so let's go with that

This is for a rickroll btw hehe

Comment: Disable all user input without root is nearly impossible. The only way that comes close to this is to start a second app after Youtube that just shows a transparent full-screen app window (overlay), so that touches got to the app and the youtube app in background is still visible. However the user can still make the Android navigation bar on the bottom or the status line at the top visible and therefore leave this mode. In any way such an needs to be developed, and app-development is off-topic here.

Comment: I do not mind the status bar or the other ones which can't be overlayed.
as for the application method; it would be viable, if only there was a such application installed on many devices (maybe a system app has a bug like that?). As for the app part, there are such applications like "lock your screen" or "screen touch lock" I would resort to these; but only if there are absolutely no other ways (excluding root).

Comment: You should edit your question and present more details on what you want to achieve and  what your restrictions are (e.g. without installing any app?, how do you execute the script - via app or adb)

Comment: the script? im just planning it to be an sh script tbh (run it from adb maybe). Not to be rude, but why does how I execute the script matter? I mean its all the same shell and (mostly?) the same permissions. As for the first part yes I will add that now.

Comment: @A68AGaming shell is not same on `adb` and apps. There are huge differences of permissions.

Comment: ok, I added to the question to assume we have adb permission :D